# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.StatusAggregator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have this gradle configuration:

***gradle***

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
    implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // Lombook
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    // Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

***application.yml configuration***

```
    server:
      port: 8080
      servlet:
        context-path: /api
    logging:
      file:
        name: ${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log
      level:
        com:
          backend: DEBUG
        org:
          springframework: DEBUG
          springframework.web: DEBUG
    spring:
      application:
        name: merchant-hub-admin-service
      profiles:
        active: dev
      data:
        web:
          pageable:
            one-indexed-parameters: true # Fix pagination starting number to start from 1
        rest:
          basePath: /engine
      jackson:
        default-property-inclusion: non_null
      jmx:
        enabled: false
      datasource:
        platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
        url: jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/test
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        username: test
        password: test
      jpa:
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
        show-sql: true
        database: postgresql
    info:
      build:
        version: 1.0
    feign:
      client:
        config:
          default:
            connectTimeout: 5000
            readTimeout: 5000
            loggerLevel: basic
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
```

When I start the application I get:

```
12:29:22.123 [main] DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver[logKeyFound:115] - Found key 'eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type Boolean
12:29:22.221 [main] ERROR SpringApplication[reportFailure:860] - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.discoveryClient
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
        at org.MerchantAdminApplication.main(MerchantAdminApplication.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration$EurekaHealthCheckHandlerConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5fa7e7ff]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/StatusAggregator
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.StatusAggregator
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
12:29:22.227 [main] DEBUG AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext[doClose:1049] - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2f4948e4, started on Sat Aug 28 12:29:01 EEST 2021
12:29:22.232 [main] WARN  SpringApplication[handleRunFailure:832] - Unable to close ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration$EurekaHealthCheckHandlerConfiguration] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5fa7e7ff]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:747)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1740)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:685)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:656)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:667)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:903)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:878)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:819)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
        at org.MerchantAdminApplication.main(MerchantAdminApplication.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/StatusAggregator
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3244)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2387)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
        ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.StatusAggregator
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Seems the same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47648888/problems-with-eureka-health-checks-in-spring-application

Comment: your eureka `healtcheck: true` probably requires actuator on classpath. So try to add `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to the classpath.

Answer (score 9):

This is because in this version actuator is optional
just add the actuator dependency to your pom or gradle dependency file like this :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or gradle:

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '2.5.6'
```